# Is it bad for performance to have an App Engine expando model with a huge number of properties?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, model, expando

I've been using a pattern in an application where I'm setting arbitrary attributes on Expando class models in an App Engine app.

This works as expected, but hasn't yet been tested with a really large data set. And over time, the number of attributes might get to be > 1000.

It also makes the table in the administration console scroll far to the right, since it needs a column for each attribute.

I figured I might save myself and others from a major pita by asking about this.

Comment: Also should mention that for each instance the attribute number will be considerably less, but the indexes might be slowed down regardless because other instances have many other attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only properties that have values set to them will get indexed.  This can be a PITA when you're trying to find all People without a LastName set.  In your case though it works out perfectly - for small entities updating the indexes will be fast, but large cases will still be possible.  Beware the upper limit on index entries per entity - I think it's 5000 right now.